# Why does kill --timeout not work?

Tags: bash, kill

When I try to execute this command which is valid according to `man 1 kill` I receive an error instead of proper functionality.

```
$ kill --timeout 1000 TERM --signal QUIT 12345
bash: kill: -timeout: invalid signal specification
```

I am using the `util-linux` version of `kill`.

Answer (score 5):

You receive an error because `bash` prioritizes a shell builtin command `kill`. When you type `man 1 kill`, the installed program is described as a "user command". You may circumvent this by using the full path of the installed program, e.g. `/usr/bin/kill`.

Comment: ... or `env kill` if you don't want to hard-code an absolute path and instead take the first `kill` utility that occurs in `$PATH`.

Answer (score -1):

In addition [@ArborealAnole](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/387827/arborealanole) answer.

Possibly the target process with pid 1234. Does not handle/trap the QUIT signal.

First test that process with pid 1234 can handle/trap QUIT signal. Than apply a timeout.

BTW: the correct QUIT signal is `SIGQUIT`. You can list available signals with `kill -l`